# android when recyclerview in a viewpager is scrolled, how to top parent scrollview scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

i make the following view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewActions.openMore()}"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_my_more" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_profile_thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_my_profile_thumbnail"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    app:profileThumbnailSrc="@{myProfile.profileUrl}" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:text="@{myProfile.urlId}"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="23dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager_my"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gnb_height" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The viewpager has two fragment with recyclerview.

when i a recyclerview in a viewpager scroll up, how to scroll the top ScrollView.
in current, only recyclervie in a viewpager is scrolled.

if you know how to solve, please answer my question.
thank you very much

Comment: try NestedScrollView

Comment: Can you please explain more in details what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Moinkhan thank you your answer, but i applied NestedScrollView, but it is not working

Comment: in nestedScrollView apply some properties like fillViewPort, NestedScrollingEnable ...

Comment: @RudrikPatel a viewpager has two fragment, each fraghemt has a recyclerview, when i recyclerview scroll, parent scrollview is not scrolled only recycerview is scrolled

Comment: @user1611241 so you want both recyclerView and  scrollview to scroll in one event??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem or not because of the lack of your code information but, please try this and let me know if this resolves your issue.

```
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: i added my code. i hope when i scroll recycler view in viewpager i want to scroll parent scrollview(id=layout_scrollview) together

Comment: So when you scroll up the recyclerview you want your profile thumbnail layout to move up as well. Right?

Answer (score -1):

use below to stop Parent getting any event.

> ```
> recyclerView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
> ```

set it to **false** when you want parent to Intercept event's of child.

if you want to stop scrolling in recycler is a special case :

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
 //special case condition
   if(x==y&& event.action== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
     return false
  }
}
```